# browser detection for internet explore

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have this javascript to detect browsers but It doesn't work in IE9. I have found several examples but couldn't make it work with my code. Could someone advise me so that it works in all browsers as it was required.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Javascript

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
                    || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
                    || "an unknown version";
            this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    var dataString = data[i].string;
                    var dataProp = data[i].prop;
                    this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
                    if (dataString) {
                            if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                                    return data[i].identity;
                    }
                    else if (dataProp)
                            return data[i].identity;
            }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index == -1) return;
            return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
            {
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "Chrome",
                    identity: "Chrome"
            },
            {       string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "OmniWeb",
                    versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
                    identity: "OmniWeb"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.vendor,
                    subString: "Apple",
                    identity: "Safari",
                    versionSearch: "Version"
            },
            {
                    prop: window.opera,
                    identity: "Opera",
                    versionSearch: "Version"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.vendor,
                    subString: "iCab",
                    identity: "iCab"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.vendor,
                    subString: "KDE",
                    identity: "Konqueror"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "Firefox",
                    identity: "Firefox"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.vendor,
                    subString: "Camino",
                    identity: "Camino"
            },
            {               // for newer Netscapes (6+)
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "Netscape",
                    identity: "Netscape"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "MSIE",
                    identity: "Explorer",
                    versionSearch: "MSIE"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "Gecko",
                    identity: "Mozilla",
                    versionSearch: "rv"
            },
            {               // for older Netscapes (4-)
                    string: navigator.userAgent,
                    subString: "Mozilla",
                    identity: "Netscape",
                    versionSearch: "Mozilla"
            }
    ],
    dataOS : [
            {
                    string: navigator.platform,
                    subString: "Win",
                    identity: "Windows"
            },
            {
                    string: navigator.platform,
                    subString: "Mac",
                    identity: "Mac"
            },
            {
                       string: navigator.userAgent,
                       subString: "iPhone",
                       identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
            {
                    string: navigator.platform,
                    subString: "Linux",
                    identity: "Linux"
            }
    ]
```

};
BrowserDetect.init();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, using the "userAgent" string is not a good way to do this. It's better to check if the browser supports features and then implement (or don't implement) the specific pieces of functionality of your site that the browsers will support.

Some sites that could help you out are http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html and http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `.ie9` class that gets added to your `<html>` element.

*Edited to use `hasClass` instead of `length`*

```
if ($("html").hasClass("ie9")) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do I have the correct syntax as far as the javascript?

Comment: `.length` isn't a function. Using `.hasClass()` is cleaner. `$("html").hasClass("ie9")`. Or `$("html").is(".ie9")` to be a little shorter.

Answer (score 0):

To detect MSIE (v6 - v7 - v8 - v9 - v10 - v11) easily

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
   // MSIE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function runvlc(){
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")!==-1|| 
(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0)){
alert('iexplorer')
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")==-1){
alert('others')
}
};
```

This one works.